# How to publish to Kafka client in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I have tried to publish to kafka in NestJs

```
 async publish<T extends IEvent>(event: T) {
    await this.client.connect();
    await this.client.send('topic', event);
  }
```

But yet not found the correct method, dispatchEvent is protected.

Edit:
using cqrs so this is inside a eventpublisher subscribed to the eventbus.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe you need the `connect` method. Have you made sure you're [subscribing to the message response](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka#message-response-subscription)? The below is a working example with a client controller and server controller:

### Client Controller

```js
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Inject,
  OnModuleDestroy,
  OnModuleInit,
  UseFilters,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientKafka } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { ExceptionFilter } from './exception.filter';

@Controller()
export class KafkaClientController implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  constructor(@Inject('KAFKA_SERVICE') private readonly kafka: ClientKafka) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    ['hello', 'error', 'skip'].forEach((key) =>
      this.kafka.subscribeToResponseOf(`say.${key}`),
    );
  }

  onModuleDestroy() {
    this.kafka.close();
  }

  @Get()
  sayHello() {
    return this.kafka.send('say.hello', { ip: '127.0.0.1' });
  }

  @Get('error')
  @UseFilters(ExceptionFilter)
  sayError() {
    return this.kafka.send('say.error', { ip: '127.0.0.1' });
  }

  @Get('skip')
  saySkip() {
    return this.kafka.send('say.skip', { ip: '127.0.0.1' });
  }
}
```

### Server Controller

```js
import { BadRequestException, Controller, UseFilters } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { OgmaSkip } from '@ogma/nestjs-module';
import { AppService } from '../../app.service';
import { ExceptionFilter } from './exception.filter';

@Controller()
export class KafkaServerController {
  constructor(private readonly service: AppService) {}

  @MessagePattern('say.hello')
  sayHello() {
    return this.service.getHello();
  }

  @UseFilters(ExceptionFilter)
  @MessagePattern('say.error')
  sayError() {
    throw new BadRequestException('Borked');
  }

  @OgmaSkip()
  @MessagePattern('say.skip')
  saySkip() {
    return this.service.getHello();
  }
}
```

The above were used for integration testing of a library I was making. You can [check out the full module setups here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/tree/master/integration/src/kafka)

Comment: I used kafka inside a cqrs publisher listening to the eventbus i will post the code later. Thats why im using connect. I switched to just using kafka js it was more convenient.

Comment: Yes, this does work. I modified sayHello() to something like:
```@Get()
  sayHello() {
    this.kafka.send('say.hello', { ip: '127.0.0.1' });
    return 'hello'
  }```

But this does not work. Is there a way to use `send()` without having to return?

Comment: You can add `.subscribe()` to it. The reason it's necessary is because it's an RxJS Observable, and they are not fired until there is a subscriber listening to it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.